# Jquery shaker to all sides

Tags: jquery, animation

is there any jquery function, to shake object to all sides? now I'm using CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spaceboots {
0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(3deg); }
10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-3deg); }
20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(4deg); }
30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(3deg); }
40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(4deg); }
50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-4deg); }
60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(3deg); }
70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-4deg); }
80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(4deg); }
90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(3deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-4deg); }
}
```

but it is working only with chrome.

Comment: css using -webkit only works on -webkit browsers, like chrome.

Comment: i know it, thats why i'm asking this question. Is there alternative for this code to work with jquery? and shake to all sides btw

Comment: Why not add transforms for other browsers as well?

Comment: how should i do it? -webkit works with chrome/safari only, how i should add transforms to other browsers/

Comment: It seems obvious you do not have a basic understanding of what you want to do. You need to go back to basics and research both jQuery and CSS3, then come back with specific question(s) that meet the requirements layed out in the [faq].

Answer (score 2):

> is there any jquery function, to shake object to all sides

No, there isn't. jQuery definitely does not have a function so specific.

Comment: I feel sarcasm in this sentence. Can you show me the right way how I should do it, sir?

Comment: There is no sarcasm, I answered the question you asked. There is no "right" way to do this, what you're trying to do is way too specific to have a "right" way.

Comment: ok, so can You show me anything, who can help me with this? any example or something?